# Question about the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I have been studying the Fundamental theorem of Algebra over the past few days, and I'm having a hard time finding the answers for my following question. I hope that someone will shine a light so I can move forward with my study.

**From Wikipedia:**

"The fundamental theorem of algebra states that every non-constant single-variable polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one complex root. This includes polynomials with real coefficients, since every real number is a complex number with its imaginary part equal to zero.

The theorem is also stated as follows: every non-zero, single-variable, degree n polynomial with complex coefficients has, counted with multiplicity, exactly n complex roots. The equivalence of the two statements can be proven through the use of successive polynomial division."

**My question is:**

Is there such a thing as a polynomial with complex (imaginary part included) coefficients? Can a polynomial be created such as $f(x) = (x-2)(x-i)(x+2i) = x^3 + (2+i)x^2 + (2+2i)x + 4$? If not, is the reason for it the fact that the coefficients of the polynomial contain an imaginary part, or because it simply defies the complex conjugate root theorem?

Thank you.

Comment: That's a polynomial, with complex (but not real) coefficients.

Comment: There are polynomials with complex coefficients, though they don't necessarily follow the complex conjugate root theorem

Comment: @J.W.Tanner so how do we generalize that statement? "For the polynomial to follow the complex root theorem, the coefficients cannot have an imaginary part"? Is that valid?

Comment: @bru1987 - not quite: consider $ix^2+i=0$.  You could make it true by making the leading coefficient real (or even $1$ by division)

Comment: the complex conjugate root theorem is about polynomials with real coefficients

Comment: @Henry so maybe "In every polynomial with non imaginary coefficients, if a complex number is a solution/root, it's complex conjugate will also be a root/solution"?

Comment: @bru1987 $(1+i)x^2 + (1+i) = 0$ has complex rather than imaginary coefficients.  If you change your "non imaginary" to "real" then you are back at the   the complex root theorem

Comment: @Henry ok, last one (hopefully): "In every polynomial $p(x)$ with real coefficients, if a complex number is a solution/root for $p(x)=0$, it's complex conjugate will also be a root/solution"?

Comment: @bru1987 - that is  essentially the complex root theorem

Comment: @Henry hahah you're right. It all makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no barrier to considering polynomials with complex coefficients and complex roots. The fundamental theorem of algebra is an assertion about those polynomials - each one factors into a product of linear factors.

When the coefficients happen to be real the roots must occur in conjugate pairs.

**Edit** in response to comment.

If the roots occur in conjugate pairs then the coefficients are real, because $(x- r)(x-\bar r)$ has real coefficients. But the roots must pair up. The polynomial
$$
(x-i)^2(x+i)
$$
has $i$ and $-i$ as roots but nonreal coefficients.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Therefore, from your statement, can I generalize "For the polynomial to follow the complex conjugate root theorem, the coefficients cannot have an imaginary part"?

Comment: @bru1987: No, *because* the complex conjugate root theorem is about **real polynomials** to begin with. If the source you are reading does not state that clearly, then it is a bad source. It is just like many high-school texts that state "$a^{b·c} = (a^b)^c$" without stating what $a,b,c$ are. That is bad, because it is false for $(a,b,c)=(-1,6,1/2)$. The theorem is: Take any real polynomial $f$ and $z∈ℂ$ such that $f(z) = 0$. Then $f(z^*) = 0$. Proof sketch: $f(z^*) = \cdots = (f(z))^* = 0$ (using the fact that $c·(z^*)^k = c^*·(z^*)^k = (c·z^k)^*$ for every $c∈ℝ$ and $z∈ℂ$ and $k∈ℕ$).

Answer (score 0):

For sure complex polynomials exist.

You can define a polynomial on any field $\mathbb F$. For example

$$ p(x) = x^2+x+1$$ is a polynomial of the field with two elements.

You can even define polynomials on rings like $\mathbb Z$ like the polynomial

$$q(x) = 3x^3-x+27.$$

Answer (score 0):

A *real* polynomial $f(X)$ (formally, an element of the polynomial ring $\Bbb R[X]$) is of the form

$$f(X)=a_nX^n+\dots+a_0~~~a_j\in\Bbb R,\,a_n\ne0$$

A *complex* polynomial $f(X)$ (formally, an element of the polynomial ring $\Bbb C[X]$) is of the form

$$f(X)=a_nX^n+\dots+a_0~~~a_j\in\Bbb C,\,a_n\ne0$$

Alternatively, in the latter case every $a_j$ admits a representation of the form $a_j=x_j+iy_j$ where $x_j,y_j\in\Bbb R$.

---

In particular, every real polynomial is a complex polynomial (since $\Bbb R\subset\Bbb C$) but not vice-versa. Your given polynomial is completely fine as polynomial *over $\Bbb C$* but not *over $\Bbb R$* as $i\notin\Bbb R$.